# What does the "-" means for the checkedId?

Tags: android

I'm figuring a code out but I don't understand the line where it says positionData = (byte) (checkedId -position1Button.getId());

What does the "-" stands for?

```
private byte positionData;
       class PositionRadioGroupListener implements android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener{

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                positionData=(byte) (checkedId -position1Button.getId());
                imageChange();
            }//onCheckedChanged
       }
```

Comment: Bad spacing, should be `checkedId - position1Button.getId()` :(

Comment: @AndrewT. So basically, what does the line means? It checks the ID of the position1Button? I can't seem to find a detailed explanation on this issue.

Comment: Literally, it will subtract the newly checked radio button's ID with button's ID. As for logical meaning... I don't know. It seems quite dangerous to process data based from operation on widget's ID.